# set combobox selected item as default for combobox in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a winforms project for a handheld device where I have multiple forms, I have one form to set the default options for another form, for example there is a comboBox on the default form for Locations which is populated with xml. what I want to do is when the user selects a location from the drop down on the defaults form and hits save, I need the selected location to be set as the default(show first) on the main form.

```
//Main Form 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = "/My Documents/AHWLtTables.txt";
    dataSet1.ReadXml(filePath);


    comboBox2.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables[8];
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "Loc";
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Desc";
}
```

This populates the comboBox with the xml data and I know that I can use SelectedIndex to set a default from the list I am just missing how to save the index # from the selection in the default options form and set it to that # in the main form. 
Or am I approaching this wrong, should I make the dataSet a public object across all forms and call on it that way somehow?

Comment: short and simple, I like it! although I am not very comfortable or familiar with xml, the file it is using is generated from a database then loaded onto the device with active sync. I'm assuming that I could still add this tag? do you have any links that might point me in the right direction

Comment: If you think the answer is correct accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How do you access to the second form?, you can send the parameter to the other form using a property (its a varible of any type with the get and set method), you can declare a property in the second form:

```
public int indexCombo {get; set;}
```

and when you call the form use something like:

```
    Form2 myForm2 as Form2();

    myForm2.indexCombo = comboBox2.selectedIndex; //I won't remember exactly the method XD sorry
//As you see first make the instace of the form and second set the value of the property

    myForm2.show();
```

Finally to show the selected index en the new form in the load of the form:

```
comboBoxForm2.selectedIndex = indexCombo;
```

Comment: thank you, I haven't got it completely figured out yet (noob over here) but I think this is what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You could add a tag to the xml file that would save the index of the combo boxes. Adding the tag to the file is simple. You can just go into the file and do so. You just need to make up for that in your c# code. A good article is [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58239-c-tutorial-reading-and-writing-xml-files/) here